# Laravel Dependent Select Value = 0

Tags: mysql, laravel, select

Storing 0 value into mysql where it suppose to save the value that was selected in dropdown! Please refer to the image that i linked in here!! Thanks

Dropdowns
https://ibb.co/wwfxzzC

Mysql
https://ibb.co/gyqLNvm

Ajax for dropdown

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#carValidatorDept').on('change', function() {
            var stateID = $(this).val();
            if (stateID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/findCityWithStateID/' + stateID,
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        if (data) {
                            $('#carValidatorName').empty();
                            $('#carValidatorName').focus;
                            $('#carValidatorName').append('<option value="">-- Select Validator Name --</option>');
                            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                $('select[name="carValidatorName"]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value.fname + '</option>');
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('#carValidatorName').empty();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#carValidatorName').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Dropdowns

```
      {!! Form::label('carValidatorDept', 'To: Department', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
      <div class="col-lg-10">
          <select name="carValidatorDept" class="form-control" id="carValidatorDept" style="width:250px">
              <option value="">-- Select dept --</option>
              @foreach ($departments as $dept)
              <option value="{{ $dept->id }}">{{ ucfirst($dept->name) }}</option>
              @endforeach
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group {{ ($errors->has('name'))?'has-error':'' }}">
      {!! Form::label('carValidatorName', 'Name', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
      <div class="col-lg-10">


          <select name="carValidatorName" class="form-control" id="carValidatorName">
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is the controller serving `findCityWithStateID`? You are having a server side problem (assuming your AJAX request sends the correct request with the proper id from the option element) but have only posted client side code.

Comment: @Elias Solved already bro..thank btw!! :)

Comment: Any other answers are welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :) Happy Coding

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#carValidatorDept').on('change', function() {
            var stateID = $(this).val();
            if (stateID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/findCityWithStateID/' + stateID,
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        if (data) {
                            $('#carValidatorName').empty();
                            $('#carValidatorName').focus;
                            $('#carValidatorName').append('<option value="">-- Select Validator Name --</option>');
                            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                $('select[name="carValidatorName"]').append('<option value="' + value.fname + '">' + key  + '</option>');
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('#carValidatorName').empty();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#carValidatorName').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!!**

```
>   $(document).ready(function() {
>          $('#carValidatorDept').on('change', function() {
>              var stateID = $(this).val();
>              if (stateID) {
>                  $.ajax({
>                      url: '/findCityWithStateID/' + stateID,
>                      type: "GET",
>                      data: {
>                          "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
>                      },
>                      dataType: "json",
>                      success: function(data) {
>                          //console.log(data);
>                          if (data) {
>                              $('#carValidatorName').empty();
>                              $('#carValidatorName').focus;
>                              $('#carValidatorName').append('<option value="">-- Select Validator Name --</option>');
>                              $.each(data, function(key, value) {
>                                  $('select[name="carValidatorName"]').append('<option value="' +
> value.fname + '">' + value.fname + '</option>');
>                              });
>                          } else {
>                              $('#carValidatorName').empty();
>                          }
>                      }
>                  });
>              } else {
>                  $('#carValidatorName').empty();
>              }
>          });
>      });  </script>
```